# Using context.SaveChanges() == 0 to test for operation success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-5

I have this ASP.NET MVC3 project that uses EF5 db-first for data access; a pattern my predecessor established was to introduce the following check for update / delete operations:

```
if (context.SaveChanges() == 0)
    throw new SqlExecutionException("...");
```

I've recently come to realize that this approach fails when used to update existing data with unchanged data, like when a user opens a window to edit stuff and presses "ok" without actually changing anything; the number of changed records is then 0, the exception throws, and that's wrong.

Looking around I've come to perceive the purpose of this check to be mistaken: in case the record has been destroyed after being pulled from the DB, EF will throw a subtype of DataException to signal that, and I cant think of any other reason for this check to exist. My predecessor is out of touch, thus my question: can I safely purge these checks from my code, supplementing them with a filter for DataExceptions on a higher level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a pattern from the C++ days. If there is a database constraint violation EF or another ORM will give you good error messages.